# visual studio: attach debugger without starting web debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, attach-to-process

I have a visual studio solution with a half dozen web application projects.  I often want to attach the debugger to a process.  When I do this, visual studio always wants to start up cassini or IIS express or do something to run the web applications in the solution.  Is there a way I can skip that, so when attaching to a process visual studio does not try to start the web applications in the current solution?

Comment: Are you using Tools, Attach to process?  Perhaps after starting to debug a project e.g. F5 or Debug, Start Debugging?  I just tried Tools, Attach to process with 1 web project, no dev servers started and VS didn't start anything extra.

Comment: I am using "Tools -> Attach to process".  Do you know specifically whether that was that a web site or web application project?

Comment: Good catch!  It was a web application project (e.g. File, New Project, ASP.NET Web Application).  I tried with a Web Site and VS2010 still didn't start the dev web server.  This is a head scratcher.  I upvote your question while I think and play around in VS.

Comment: Its strange you don't see this problem as I've had several people try this and they see the debug servers start no matter what process they attach to.  Maybe I need to try to isolate the issue more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the project properties, there's a setting called "Development Server" -> "Always Start When Debugging."  Might be worth a shot.

[image]

Comment: I feel like I may have known that in the past :O